# No picture on HDMI Output from a Pioneer 921 AV Receiver to a Projector

Tags: hdmi, mac-mini, projector, av-receiver

I am trying hard to tackle a what seemed to be simple problem if wiring my setup together. The setup:

- Mac Mini (2011) with HDMI Output
- Pioneer 921 K AV Receiver
- Acer HD Projector (HDMI)

When I hook up my Mac Mini directly to the Projector with a 30 foot (10 meter) HDMI Cable everything is just fine. The picture is sharp and the colors brilliant.

However, when I send HDMI to the receiver (into the BD HDMI Input) then I get absolutely no HDMI output to the projector, it keeps saying "no signal".

Is there perhaps some magic combination of setup buttons that may help me resolve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

Have you seen [this forum article](http://www.avsforum.com/t/1226539/trouble-connecting-computer-to-av-receiver-via-hdmi)? It may be relevant to what you're experiencing.

Specifically this line:

> Receivers won't transcode digital HDMI video to analog component output. You'll need to either run an HDMI cable from the receiver to your display or switch to analog out from the computer (with a VGA or DVI to Component adapter).

Comment: Hi, I am working with HDMI only. HDMI leaving the Mac Mini into the Receiver, and HDMI leaving the receiver into the projector. Direct connection from the Mac Mini to the projector works fine.

Comment: Solved the problem by replacing the HDMI Cable with a more expensive one.